# nftables not working, am I doing it right?

Tags: nftables

I was following tutorial at https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page

Here is what I did.

```
#uname -a
Linux delor 4.9.0-0.bpo.6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1~bpo8+1 (2018-05-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# sudo nft add table ip filter
# sudo nft add chain ip filter output { type filter hook input priority 0 \; }
# sudo nft add chain ip filter input { type filter hook input priority 0 \; }
# sudo nft add rule filter output ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter
# ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
# sudo nft -nn list table filter

table ip filter {
    chain output {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
            ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter packets 0 bytes 0
    }

    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

We see that the tables are set up (as shown in the tutorial). However the counter did not increase.

**Did I miss something? Was I supposed to do something else to enable it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *output* chain is using the *input* hook. So it's actually a second chain working for *input*. Its name doesn't matter. What does matter is its hook: *input*.

Use instead:

```
# sudo nft add chain ip filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 \; }
```

Comment: Opps a cut and paste error. Thanks. I fixed it, it now works.